# How to add an external library in maven intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-14

I copied some code from github and I have a problem with libraries. My code looks like:

[image: code]

When i click on Authentication to add a maven dependency

[image: click]

it shows that there is no results

[image: no results]

What I do wrong? Should I install anything before clicking "add maven dependency" ?

Comment: don't just blindly click "add dependency". research the one you need, and add it manually. that way, you're sure you have the right library and it's right version.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

To your pom.xml 
Or just search for another dependency. https://mvnrepository.com/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add maven dependency in pom file:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core